# How do I set multiplier value of root Stack View (equal width to super view with 0.7 multiplier) 0.7 for iPhones and 0.6 for iPads?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I did a percentage based width for root Stack View.

First I made  root stack view equal width to super view and multiplier to  0.7 to get the 70 % of subview. And then horizontally center in a container.It works for all iPhones but it is bigger for iPads. I want make multiplier from 0.7 to 0.5 or 0.6 so that root view may seen perfectly for iPads.

I did not find a + (plus) sign next to multiplier to make it (regular-regular for iPads).

All I want is to make  root stack view get  60 percent width of superview for all iPhones and 70 percent width of superview for all iPads .

Is there way to change multiplier value 0.7 for iPhones and 0.6 for iPads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is! It could easily be achieved with Size classes, but unfortunately you have to add another *constraint* for different size class rather than different *multiplier* for the same constraint.

1) Assuming you have view like that:
[image]

2) All you have to do is to add another subview-superview equal-width constraint:

[image]

[image]

3) Getting conflicting constraints, of course:

[image]

4) Set required multiplier for iPad (0.6) on new constraint

5)The tricky part: enable old contraint for all Size classes except `Regual Width`, `Regular Height` (an iPad size class) and vise-versa for new constraint:

5.1) add wR hR "variation" for the first constraint:
[image]

and disable it: 
[image]

Do the same for the second constraint, but disable it for "install" variation.

At the end both constants should look like:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, if we preview iPhone, we see only the first constraint activated, in iPad preview only the second constraint activated.

Comment: Thank you so much. I now understand what is installed too. I don't know how to thank you !

Comment: @John glad to help :)